# Detecting a certain amount of violet in an image - follow-up

Tags: c#, image

I'm trying to write a program to detect the colour violet in an image.
As discussed in my previous [Post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/196014/detecting-a-certain-amount-of-violet-in-an-image) @Johnbot suggested that I try using [HSL / HSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) to determine if the pixel is some shade of violet.

```
this.button2.Click += async (sender, e) =>
{
    Task task = Task.Run(() =>
    {
      ProcessImage(pictureBox1.Image);
    });
      Task.WaitAll(task);
      await task;
    };
}

    private void ProcessImage(Image image)
    {
        if (image == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        using (var selectedImage = new Bitmap(image))
        {
            double total = 0;
            double infected = 0;

            Color violet = Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.Violet);
            Color selectedPixel;

            for (int x = 0; x < selectedImage.Width; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < selectedImage.Height; y++)
                {
                    selectedPixel = selectedImage.GetPixel(x, y);

                    if (selectedPixel.GetHue() == (violet.GetHue()))
                    {
                        infected++;
                    }
                    total++;
                }
            }
            //TODO: Needs to be rounded
            //Change the value eg: 0.0030, 0.0010, 0.0050
            try
            {
                double percentage = (infected / total);
                Console.WriteLine(percentage);

                double result;
                if (Double.TryParse(Convert.ToString(percentage).Substring(0, 6), out result))
                {
                    if (result > 0.0017)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Image is infected: {0:P}", percentage));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Threshold not reached");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No Violet Pixels Whatsoever were found");
            }
            finally
            {
                selectedImage.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```

Here are two of the images I'm working with.
The first one has the colour violet in it quite a lot with a percentage of 0.64% or 0.00636199367565126
[image: Image0]
The second one from what I can tell doesn't have any violet in it, however the application believes it does with 0.36% violet pixels or 0.00355871886120996.
[image: image1]
The code above is working so to speak, however is there something I could be doing to improve it for reliability and performance?
 I did see a post about [Bitmap locking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24701703/c-sharp-faster-alternatives-to-setpixel-and-getpixel-for-bitmaps-for-windows-f?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) however because its only going to be scanning a image every hour or so for any violet pixels, it didn't implement it, should i still do it?

Comment: 0.64% seems way below what can be observed from the naked eye. There seems to be more than 10% or even 20%, don't you think?

Comment: I believe so too, I think I need to working out a better way to  compare the injected and total pixels.

Comment: Mathias raised a good point. Judging by results you are getting, this implementations hardly qualifies as "working code". You should check the pixel's hue against some range: `violetHue - 10 < pixelHue < violetHue + 10` (arbitrary numbers here, you have to figure out the exact range yourself).

Comment: As my previous answer you should not write to the UI in a method that calculates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> this.button2.Click += async (sender, e) =>
> {
>     Task task = Task.Run(() =>
>     {
>       ProcessImage(pictureBox1.Image);
>     });
>       Task.WaitAll(task);
>       await task;
>     };
> }
> ```

Is the indentation like that in the original, or did it get corrupted by the tab-to-space conversion of StackExchange?

What's going on with the task? I don't know much about async event handlers, but as far as general async/await usage you only need one of `Task.WaitAll(task)` or `await task`.

What stops me from mashing the button and spinning off loads of tasks? Normally you would want to prevent a second click by opening a modal dialog (denying access to the button) or disabling the button, and then using `ContinueWith` to undo the block in the GUI thread when the task finishes.

---

> ```
>     private void ProcessImage(Image image)
>     {
>         if (image == null)
>         {
>             return;
>         }
>         using (var selectedImage = new Bitmap(image))
> ```

If the image is already a bitmap, this is unnecessary and slow. It's probably worth having two cases and factoring out the code which works with `Bitmap` to a separate method:

```
    if (image is Bitmap) Process(image as Bitmap);
    else using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(image)) Process(bitmap);
```

---

> ```
>             double total = 0;
>             double infected = 0;
> ```

That's an odd choice for counters. Why not use an integer type and coerce to double when dividing?

---

> ```
>             for (int x = 0; x < selectedImage.Width; x++)
>             {
>                 for (int y = 0; y < selectedImage.Height; y++)
>                 {
>                     selectedPixel = selectedImage.GetPixel(x, y);
> ```

This is **slow**. A loop over `GetPixel` is always slow, and it's worse when the outer loop is over `x` because you lose cache locality. If you care about speed, use `LockBits` and switch the loops.

---

> ```
>                     if (selectedPixel.GetHue() == (violet.GetHue()))
> ```

`GetHue()` returns a float. `==` comparisons on non-integer numeric types are generally inadvisable. You should almost certainly test whether `selectedPixel.GetHue()` is within a small distance of `violet.GetHue()`. How wide a range is a parameter which you may need to tune to get the results you expect.

---

> ```
>                 if (Double.TryParse(Convert.ToString(percentage).Substring(0, 6), out result))
> ```

??! Why? And if the specs require you to round to an exact number of decimal places and that's non-negotiable, why use `double` instead of `decimal`?

---

> ```
>             catch
>             {
>                 MessageBox.Show("No Violet Pixels Whatsoever were found");
>             }
> ```

Under what circumstances can this catch anything? The only one I can see is if `total == 0`, in which case the error message should really be that the image was empty.

---

> ```
>             finally
>             {
>                 selectedImage.Dispose();
>             }
> ```

This is unncessary: it's already in a `using` statement.

Comment: thank you for your reply mate, Yeah im not too fussed at this stage about the speed of the image processing, as long as it does it at least 90 - 95 % correct. I had added your changes, thanks again! oh just quickly for that catch block, I added that because if there were less infected pixels than total pixels, it would through an error when dividing them, this could be maybe because its not a decimal?

Comment: Ah, maybe you were getting an exception from `Substring(0, 6)` because the string was shorter than that. Another reason to ditch the conversion to string...

Answer (score 2):

The hardest part is figuring out what violet is. The math gets complex in a hurry and it can be hard to come up with a right answer.

As you know you can't just compare the distance between two colors because red is the same distance from blue as blue is from green, etc. As a completely abstract example just look at the standard basis vectors (*255) in ℝ³.

[image]

So if you are comparing like this there will be this fine line where on one side you have violet and on the other side, not violet. I know you're using HSL but I suspect you're having a similar problem and all the tweaking in the world won't help. Trying to work out the math yourself is a losing battle too. The good news is this amazingly awesome and nice website has done the work for us http://www.easyrgb.com/en/math.php.

I used it on my [color picker](https://github.com/smchughinfo/color) which you might find useful as it finds the closest named color and already has some working code.

Comment: Hey mate, you’re not wrong, it is incredibly difficult to detect all shades of violet and nothing else.